# Передать адрес как переменную

Tags: javascript

Я хочу написать функцию, которая принимает ссылку на определенный объект (адрес) как аргумент и в конце выполнения присваивает полученный результат по указанному адресу. Пример:

```
var obj = {}
obj.firstProp = null;
obj.secondProp = null;
obj.thirdProp = null;

function export(target)  {
    // выполняется код
    var result = 5;
    target = result;
}

export(obj.secondProp); // Не выполняется, т.к. ссылка на obj.subObj возвращает null
```

Как мне указать obj.secondProp в качестве адреса либо решить эту проблему иным путем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` вроде зарезервировано JavaScripto'oм :)

Переименуй функцию, во первых. Во вторых объекты и являются ссылочными типами, а ты передаёшь значение одного из свойств. Как вариант - передавать два параметра, ссылку на объект и свойство:

```
var obj = {}
obj.firstProp = null;
obj.secondProp = null;
obj.thirdProp = null;

function exports(target, property)  {
    if(target.hasOwnProperty(property)){
        target[property] = 5;
    }
}

exports(obj, "secondProp");
console.log(obj.secondProp);
```

Comment: по типу exports_f(obj, secondProp); Верно?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov пример кода в ответе, переделал под рабочий.